# Generating a walking gait for a 6-legged robot

Tags: drake

I'm trying to generate a walking gait for a 6-legged robot with drake. I haven't been able to find any (fully documented) examples of what I'm currently trying to do, but the classes I see in the c++ documentation lead me to believe it might be possible.

I found [this paper](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/robotics-center/public_papers/Posa13.pdf) a great "guide" for what to do.

My understanding of the steps to solving this problem are as follows:

1. Derive the manipulator equation for the 6-legged hexapod/make drake compute this automatically
2. Figure out how to add the constraints from the aforementioned paper to a mathematical program with the contact forces and control inputs as decision variables
3. Experiment with different cost-functions (like the one used for the fastrunner gait, also in the paper)

The classes used in [this folder](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/multibody/optimization) would be quite usefull, but I don't know how to use these in pydrake (I didn't see any bindings for them in the pydrake documentation other than staticequilibrium problem)

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it even possible to do this with drake?
2. How can you use the [Manipulatorequationconstraintclass](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_manipulator_equation_constraint.html) as well as the other classes in the aforementioned folder in pydrake?
3. Is my understanding of the problem complete, and if not what am I missing?

I realize this is probably a very scattered question, I'm very inexperienced and doubly lost ;), but any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible to use Drake for this. This [LittleDog notebook](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/a252c451657c25b93be3a324d613864dcb6ced8c/examples/littledog.ipynb) example is pretty similar to what you're trying to do. Unlike the Posa reference, this example fixes the gait (foot contact sequence), but for each gait it uses optimization to solve for all of the motions.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'll take a close look at it. Out of curiosity, did fixing the gait improve the results of the optimization?

Comment: The optimization routines will be much more likely to find good solutions when the mode sequence is fixed.  The "contact implicit" version of the problem, which tries to solve the mode sequence and the motions simultaneously, tends to have many more local minima.  https://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/contact.html